# Change find method in rails using model assotiations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Now i have such model:

```
class CrossList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price_list  
end

class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cross_lists
end
```

and i have such code in method:

```
@search_res = CrossList.search(search_condition)
@prlist = PriceList.find(:first, :conditions => { :id => @search_res.map(&:price_list_id)}, :order => 'price desc')
```

but how i can do this using model assotiations? i can write

```
@prlist = @search_res.price_lists
```

but is this right? But also it must be sorted, as find do, how i can do this?

also what is best? find, or assotiations?

(newbie in rails)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the order on association with `:order`, like so:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :employees, order: "age DESC"
end
```

Employees will be ordered by default:

```
Company.all.sample.employees
```

Yes, use associations in this scenario.